# Apache Spark job is going in SUBMITTED state in standalone cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

Apache Spark job is going in SUBMITTED state even if there is enough cores and memory available.

Spark 1.2.1 cluster with standalone manager has:

Total nodes:3
Total cores:8 cores
Total memory:14 GB

Out of this,
First application is using:
1Gb memory and 2 cores so Cluster still has 13GB memory and 6 Cores available.
But after submitting another application it is going to the submitted state and wait for the first application to complete.

Why it is not getting started immediately?why does it wait for other application to complete?

Comment: you have 2 slaves in a standalone mode cluster? for what purpose considering that you are not in a full distributed environement?

Comment: Sorry.I have 3 nodes in cluster.

Comment: How can you have 3 nodes in a standalone cluster? A standalone cluster is a pseudo-distributed single node cluster where the master and the slave share the same resources.

Comment: I have used  standalone cluster manager to setup cluster.Should I use Mesos or Yarn cluster manager ?

Comment: I have never used mesos before and I'm not aware of any standalone cluster manager.  Yarn is a compute and resource management framework in Apache Hadoop and I have a feeling that you are mixing it up with what is administrative cluster management like cloudera manager...

Comment: @AbhinandanSatpute any luck in finding reason? we are facing the same issue